# How do I truncate post loop content in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress(v4.6.1) website locally, with a front page which I am also using as the page to display latest news.

It loops out each post, and **I would like to know how to truncate the content in each loop**, as it is currently just displaying all of the content from each post.

The code for the template looping out the content:

```
            <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>

            <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the_excerpt() ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Comment: @JazzCat says, you need to replace the_content() by the_excerpt in wp-content/themes/your-theme/template-parts/content-post.php

Answer (score 2):

We need to see the code from the `template-parts/content.php` file.   I suspect it is using [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) to render out the content to the browser.  You can open it and check that out.

The WordPress function `the_content` will, by default, render out all of the content.  To limit the content displayed, you have choices:

1. Use [`the_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) instead of the `the_content()`.
2. Or you'll need to write a truncate function.

### Using Excerpts

The first option is to use the excerpts instead of grabbing all of the content.  In WordPress, the excerpts are a snippet of the content with the HTML markup stripped out.  By default, it gives you 55 words of content.

**When to Use This Option**

This option is the easiest as you are letting WordPress handle the truncating process.  You would use this option when you don't care about preserving the HTML markup within the editor itself.

**How to Change the Number of Words**

To change the number of words, you register to the filter event and then return the number of words that you want.  In this example, you are stating you want 200 words.

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'change_excerpt_number_words_length' );
/**
 * Change the number of words for the excerpts.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return int
 */
function change_excerpt_number_words_length() {
    return 200;
}
```

### Truncate Content

The second option requires you to write a function that truncates "text" to a set number of words or characters.

**When to Use This Option**

You would use this option when you want to preserve the HTML markup.  Excerpts strip out the line breaks, paragraphs, etc.  With this option, you are using `get_the_content()` and then filtering the return by truncating it.  The shortcodes and HTML markup as written in the editor are preserved.

**How**

Here is where you will need some PHP and WordPress Core knowledge and chops.  Essentially, you want to register a callback to the `the_content` filter in order to grab all of the content. Then you'll strip out the shortcodes. Finally, you'll pass it to a truncating function.

This truncating function is adapted from WordPress Core:

```
/**
 * Truncate the incoming string of text to a set number of words.
 * It preserves the HTML markup.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * NOTE: This function is adapted from WordPress Core's `wp_trim_words()`
 * function.  It does the same functionality, except it does not strip out
 * the HTML tag elements.
 *
 * @param string $text
 * @param int $words_limit
 * @param string $more_text
 *
 * @return string
 */
function truncate_text( $text, $words_limit = 55, $more_text = '&hellip;' ) {

    $separator = ' ';

    /*
     * translators: If your word count is based on single characters (e.g. East Asian characters),
     * enter 'characters_excluding_spaces' or 'characters_including_spaces'. Otherwise, enter 'words'.
     * Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( strpos( _x( 'words', 'Word count type. Do not translate!' ), 'characters' ) === 0 && preg_match( '/^utf\-?8$/i', get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) ) {
        $text = trim( preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ), ' ' );
        preg_match_all( '/./u', $text, $words_array );
        $words_array = array_slice( $words_array[0], 0, $words_limit + 1 );
        $separator = '';
    } else {
        $words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $words_limit + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    }

    if ( ! count( $words_array ) > $words_limit ) {
        return implode( $separator, $words_array );
    }

    array_pop( $words_array );
    $text = implode( $separator, $words_array );
    return $text . $more_text;
}
```

Then you need to register to the `the_content` event:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'truncate_the_content', 99);
/**
 * Truncate the content to a set number of words.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param string $text
 *
 * @return string
 */
function truncate_the_content( $text ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    return truncate_text( $text );
}
```

Finally, make sure you are running the truncate where you want to avoid limiting pages and single posts.  Or you can add a conditional check using [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular).  If it is, then the text is just returned and not truncated.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'truncate_the_content', 99);
/**
 * Truncate the content to a set number of words.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param string $text
 *
 * @return string
 */
function truncate_the_content( $text ) {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        return $text;
    }

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    return truncate_text( $text );
}
```

This should get you started in the right direction.

### Disclaimer

There are a lot of limiter/truncating techniques.  The above strategy is just one of them.

Comment: The truncate_text function works well, although I'd add the following code just before the return to make the 'more text' link to the permalink.

`$more_text = '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $more_text . '</a>';`